# How to find the 4 coordinates (lat-long) of a pixel (cell) in a global file?

Tags: r, geolocation, raster, gis

I am using a climate variable that can be downloaded from here:

```
  ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/DATASETS/nsidc0301_amsre_ease_grid_tbs/global/
```

This file is a binary (matrix) file with `586 lines and 1383 columns` (global map).
I would like to know the 4 coordinates (lat-long) of a pixel (cell)`.

more info about the file :

```
These data are provided in EASE-Grid projections global cylindricalat 25 km resolution, are two-
      byte 
    Spatial Coordinates:
    N: 90°     S: -90°     E: 180°     W: -180°
```

use the raster package and convert the data to raster objects:

```
 file<- readBin("ID2r1-AMSRE-ML2010001A.v03.06H", integer(), size=2,  n=586*1383, signed=T)
 m = matrix(data=file,ncol=1383,nrow=586,byrow=TRUE)
 r = raster(m, xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90)
```

Now the file is a properly spatially referenced object, but without a full specification of the cylindrical projection used you can't get back to lat-long coordinates.

There some more info here http://nsidc.org/data/ease/tools.html including a link to some grids that have the lat-long of grid cells for that grid system:

ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/tools/easegrid/lowres_latlon/

```
      MLLATLSB  "latitude"
      MLLonLSB  "longitude"
```

so for example we can create a raster of latitude for the cells in your data grid:

```
> lat <- readBin("MLLATLSB",integer(), size=4,  n=586*1383, endian="little")/100000
> latm = matrix(data=lat,ncol=1383,nrow=586,byrow=TRUE)
> latr = raster(latm, xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90)
```

and then `latr[450,123]` is the latitude of cell [450,123] in my data. Repeat with `MLLONLSB` for longitude.

However this is not sufficient(one lat and long for each pixel) as I would like to compare with ground based measurements so I need to define my region which correspond to this pixel (25 * 25 km or 0.25 degrees). for this purpose I have to know the 4 coordinates (lat-long) of that pixel (cell).
Thanks for any help

Comment: is [this](http://nsidc.org/data/atlas/epsg_3410.html) the epsg code of this particular data?

Comment: I'm afraid it is not exactly that. The extent is not the same when compared with data from EASE Grid usgin EPSG 3410 data. Also 3410 is metric (check extents and values). [link for Bg Temp data](http://nsidc.org/data/nsidc-0301). Could you check this?

Comment: Actually is may be fine, taking as reference the image provided [here](http://nsidc.org/data/docs/daac/nsidc0301_amsre_gridded_tb.gd.html#spatialcover). I'm not being able to properly set resolution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EASE GRID uses a Global Cylindrical Equal-Area Projection defined by EPSG 3410, which is metric. As long as I see it, spatial extent should be provided in meters, not geographic coordinates.
From  [here](http://nsidc.org/cgi-bin/mapserv?zoomdir=0&zoomsize=2&zoom_to=full_extent&layer=lat_long_grid&layer=coastlines&imgxy=200.0+83.5&imgext=-17592298.982036+-7344784.825+17592298.982036+7344784.825&map=%2FWEB%2FINTERNET%2FMMS%2Fatlas%2Fepsg3410_grids.map&savequery=true&mapext=shapes&layer=land) we see that map extent coordinates are:

xmin: -17609785.303313

ymin: -7389030.516717

xmax: 17698276.686747

ymax: 7300539.133283

So slightly changing your code we have this

```
library(raster)
library('rgdal')
wdata <- 'D:/Programacao/R/Raster/Stackoverflow'
wshp <- 'S:/Vetor/Administrativo/Portugal'
#setwd(wdata)
file <- readBin(file.path(wdata, "ID2r1-AMSRE-ML2010001D.v03.06H"),
               integer(), size=2,  n=586 * 1383, signed=T)
m <- matrix(data = file, ncol = 1383, nrow = 586, byrow = TRUE)
-17609785.303313 -7389030.516717 17698276.686747 7300539.133283
rm <- raster(m, xmn = -17609785.303313, xmx = 17698276.686747,
             ymn = -7389030.516717, ymx = 7300539.133283)
proj4string(rm) <- CRS('+init=epsg:3410')

> rm
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 586, 1383, 810438  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 25530.05, 25067.53  (x, y)
extent      : -17609785, 17698277, -7389031, 7300539  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:3410 +proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371228 +b=6371228 +units=m +no_defs 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 0, 3194  (min, max)

writeRaster(rm, file.path('S:/Temporarios', 'easegrridtest.tif'), overwrite = TRUE)
plot(rm, asp = 1)
```

[image: ID2r1-AMSRE-ML2010001D.v03.06H]

We can now overlay some spatial data

```
afr <- readOGR(dsn = file.path(wdata), layer = 'Africa_final1_dd84')
proj4string(afr) <- CRS('+init=epsg:4326') # Asign projection 
afr1 <- spTransform(afr, CRS(proj4string(rm)))

plot(afr1, add = T)
```

[image]

Now you can start playing with extract extent of your ROI, possibly with `extent()`

I'm not happy with the spatial adjustment. With this approach I got a huge error. I'm not sure about the position error but it is described for this product. Maybe something with the extent parameters.

Since you are interested in use it against ground measures, you could polygonize your ROI and use it in your GPS or GIS.

[image: Africa contintnet overlayr to AESE-Grid in QGIS]

Also you could get extent of cells of interest with something like:

Choose an aproximate coordinate, identify cell and get the extent:

```
cell <- cellFromXY(rm, matrix(c('x'= -150000, 'y' =200000), nrow = 1, byrow = T))
r2 <- rasterFromCells(rm, cell, values=TRUE)
extent(r2)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : -172759.8 
xmax        : -147229.7 
ymin        : 181362 
ymax        : 206429.6
```

And maybe identify a ROI (single cell) in a map (or plot)

```
cell <- cellFromXY(rm, matrix(c('x'= -1538000, 'y' =1748000), nrow = 1, byrow = T))
r2 <- rasterFromCells(rm, cell, values=TRUE)
r2p <- as(r2, 'SpatialPolygons')
extr2 <- extent(r2) + 300000
plot(rm,  col = heat.colors(6), axes = T, ext = extr2)
plot(afr1, add = T, col = 'grey70')
plot(r2p, add = T)
```

[image: Identify ROI area in a map]

### For a particular area

And assuming that by cell you mean column and row values, you could proceed with `raster::cellFromRowCol`

```
cell2 <- cellFromRowCol(rm, rownr = mycellnrow, colnr = mycellnrow)
r3 <- rasterFromCells(rm, cell2, values=TRUE)
r3p <- as(r3, 'SpatialPolygons')
extr3 <- extent(r3) + 3000000
```

In this particular case, 123 and 450 seems to be far from any continental area...

Hope it helps.

More info on AMSR-E/Aqua Daily Gridded Brightness Temperatures [here](http://nsidc.org/data/docs/daac/nsidc0301_amsre_gridded_tb.gd.html#spatialcover)

Comment: @sacvf Could you provide it in decimal degrees (unprojected coordinates)?